# How can I solve this equation in $3$ variables for non negative integral solutions where upper limit of these variables is given

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

> Solve  for non negative integral solutions $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 48 \text{ such that} \; \;
> x_1 \leq 17 \; x_2 \leq 6 \; x_3 \leq 35$

Define,

$A: \text{set of all non negative integral solutions that have } x_1 \leq 17$

$B: \text{set of all non negative integral solutions that have } x_2 \leq 6$

$C: \text{set of all non negative integral solutions that have } x_1 \leq 35$

$U: \text{set of all non negative integral solutions}$

We are interested in $|A \cap B \cap C| =| U\setminus [A^C \cup B^C \cup C^C]| = 
|U| - |U \cap [A^C \cup B^C \cup C^C]| = |U| - |A^C \cup B^C \cup C^C|  = |U| - [|A^C| + |B^C| + |C^C| - \big( |A^C \cap B^C |+ |A^C \cap C^C |+ |B^C \cap C^C| \big) + |A^C \cap B^C \cap C^C| ] $

Now I know exactly how to calculate this but I think it is too much work. Is there an easier way to get around this?

at this point, I would proceed like this:

for |U|: we solve $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 48  \; \; x_1 \geq 0 \; x_2 \geq 0 \; x_3 \geq 0$

so $|U|= C(50,2)$

for $|A^C|$. we solve  $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 48  \; \; x_1 \geq 18 \; x_2 \geq 0 \; x_3 \geq 0$

so $|A^C| = C(32,2) $

similarly, $|B^C| = C(43,2) \; \;|C^C| = C(14,2)$

for $|A^C \cap B^C|$ : we solve $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 48  \; \; x_1 \geq 18 \; x_2 \geq 7 \; x_3 \geq 0$

$|A^C \cap B^C| = C(25,2)\ldots$ and so on.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is fine, but you can reduce the amount of computation. Multiply the equation by $-1$ and rewrite as
$$(17-x_1)+(6-x_2)+(35-x_3)=10$$
Letting $y_1=17-x_1, y_2=6-x_2, y_3=35-x_3$, you want to find the number of non-negative solutions to $$y_1+y_2+y_3=10$$ such that $y_2\leq 6$. Notice that for each solution $(y_1,y_2,y_3)$ you're going to have $0\leq x_1\leq 17, 0\leq x_2\leq 6,0\leq x_3\leq 35$.